# How to extract response from JMeter where there is no field and only response data is in the response?

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to extract values from the response in `JMeter` but in my response I have only response data and no field so I wanted to ask what regular expression can I use? I tried using `"(.+?)"` but it's not working, if I remove the "" the data is extracted but every character is place in every match count. I wanted it to be in one string in one match count.

```
Sample Response:
0f9a400332d42c28a39d98c818328a323767197a5c844c9a2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Regular Expression in Regular Expression Extractor :

> (.*) you can also use (.+)

[image]

Add this Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the Sampler returning Response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save a single line of alphanumeric characters the relevant regular expression would be `(\w+)`, as per [Regular Expressions](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html) guide:

> You can use metacharacter `\w` for a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Recall that metacharacter \d can be used for a digit [0-9].
>
> `\w+` matches one or more word characters (same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`).

[image]

---

If you want to save **full response** into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and the response can contain special characters, line breaks, whatever you can go for `(?s)(^.*)` regular expression where:

- `()` = grouping
- `(?s)` = single line modifier
- `^` = line start
- `.` = wild-card character
- `*` = repetition

Source: [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter/)

Alternative option is using [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) and provide 2 empty left and right boundaries